# Using Session Variables in AJAX form (Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Users on my site are able to store session variables in two places: 1. PHP form for single applicant page; 2. AJAX form for all the apllicants page. 
I use WP Session manager to store session variables. The PHP form works fine and inserts the value to session: $wp_session[$value] = $applicantid;
Now the AJAX form does not recognize it, though it used to work in PHP form (echo $wp_session[$ID] has a value 'checked' but doesn't return that in AJAX form):

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="checking" value="'.get_the_ID().'" name="'.get_the_ID().'" style="margin-top:5px;"'; 
echo $wp_session[$ID]; 
echo '/>Connect';
```

Also when the function below is called from AJAX form, $wp_session doesn't get filled (but the function is called, that part works fine as it returns value to AJAX):

```
function get_my_option()
{
 if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {
$value = $_POST['value'];
$applicantid = get_field('applicant id', $value);
$wp_session[$value] = $applicantid;
print($value);
exit();
}
}
```

I am wondering if there is some other method to store variables in AJAX or if I am doing something wrong here. What I want to accomplish is that visitors would be able to select the candidates on single candidate page and also select candidates on all candidates page and that those values would be remembered until they want to contact them all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and only working method for me to store variables was using JavaScript Cookies. This was used to set cookies in AJAX function's success function (with the response value-applicantid in this case) and PHP page using JS - cookies could be read everywhere now, between PHP and AJAX:

```
document.cookie = "applicantid"+"="+encodeURIComponent(applicantid)+expires+"; path=/";
```

This was used to read cookie value by name (don't forger IE8 and earlier versions do not support .trim() function):

```
  function getCookie(cname)
  {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(name.length,c.length));
  }
return "";
  }
```

Don't forget to include path=/ so that cookies could be set and read between different pages. I hope this may help somebody. Thanks for all the downvotes.